# print df -h output in one line in ksh shell

Tags: unix

I want to print `df -h` output in one line.
Our FS name is very long because of which `df -h` output is going in another line.


after using `df -PH` in bash shell, I am able to print command output in one line but df -PH is not working in ksh shell.

How to print df -h output in one line in KSH shell?

For example

```
Filesystem             size   used  avail capacity  Mounted on 
/plorm/su/lb/lir/l_pap3rs_90_lib 
   16G   5.9G   9.4G    39%    /plrm/sv/ib/li1
```

This should come

```
Filesystem             size   used  avail capacity  Mounted on   
 /plorm/su/lb/lir/l_pap3rs_90_lib   16G   5.9G   9.4G    39%    /plrm/sv/ib/li1
```

Thanks.

Comment: `df -h | tr -d \\n`

Comment: @WilliamPursell this has removed new line completely. I just need to prevent FS going to next line if FS name is too big.

Comment: Then add another newline: `df -h | tr -d \\n; echo`

Comment: @WilliamPursell sorry, but this is also not working. I have added example in my question.

Comment: There a a lot of ways to do what you want.  Try `df -h | { read a; echo "$a"; tr -d \\n; echo; }`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Sorry, again not working. You commands are giving me next FS in previous line. I don't want to mix next FS name in previous. I just to prevent current FS name going to newline if names are too big.

Comment: Does ` ... | expand -1` help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
COLUMNS=1000 df -h
```

or:

```
df -h | awk 'NF==1{printf "%s", $0; next}1'
```

or:

```
df -h | awk 'NF!=1; NF==1{ printf "%s", $0}'
```